# Counterexample of L'Hospital by otto stolz

Tags: calculus, limits

L'Hôpital's rule states that for functions f and g which are differentiable on an open interval I except possibly at a point c contained in I, if $\lim _{x\to c}f(x)=\lim _{x\to c}g(x)=0{\text{ or }}\pm \infty ,$ and $g'(x)\neq0$ for all x in I with x ≠ c, and  $\lim _{x\to c}{\frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}} $ exists, then

$\lim _{x\to c}{\frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}}=\lim _{x\to c}{\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}} $

The necessity of the condition that ${\displaystyle g'(x)\neq 0}$ near $c$ can be seen by the following counterexample due to Otto Stolz. Let $f(x)=x+\sin x\cos x$ and $g(x)=f(x)e^{\sin x}.$ Then there is no limit for $f(x)/g(x)$ as $ x\to \infty $. However,
\begin{aligned}{\frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}}&={\frac {2\cos ^{2}x}{(2\cos ^{2}x)e^{\sin x}+(x+\sin x\cos x)e^{\sin x}\cos x}}\\[4pt]&={\frac {2\cos x}{2\cos x+x+\sin x\cos x}}e^{-\sin x},\end{aligned}

which tends to 0 as $x\to \infty $.

This is a reference from wikipedia on l hospitals rule, but i find this counterexample rather unclear-- does this mean, if for example I were to evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 1}\dfrac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(x^2-1)}$$ in which $f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)$ and $g(x)=x^2-1$, If i used l'hospital, i would have violated the rules because $g'(x)=2x,$ which is equal to zero when $x=0$.

The wikipedia counterexample is saying exactly that, isn't it? in the wikipedia counterexample, $g'(x)=0$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$? Or did I get the counterexample wrong? could anyone provide more counterexamples of the sort? Thanks!

Comment: 'near' $c$ is the key. For $g$ defined above, $g'(x)$ is zero for all $x = (k+1/2)\pi$, so for any neighbourhood of $\infty$, there is some $x$ where $g'(x)$ is zero. For your function, we can say $0$ and $1$ are quite far away, so there is some neighbourhood of $1$ such that $(x^2-1)' \ne 0$